# GND plane isn't connecting to terminals?

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

Eagle CAD version 8 on Windows 11:

[image]

I have `GND` pads (75, 69) AND `GND` polygon. Why are they not connected after *Ratsnest* operation?

### Update

How can I fix this airwire?

[image]

All vias are GND:

[image]

Comment: I always route a track from the pad into the polygon (open end) to make it work. You have to hit Ratsnest again after that.

Comment: In version6 it worked. Shitty software..

Comment: That is - sadly -  true!

Comment: Could you check my update please? Drives me crazy :/

Comment: `How can I fix this airwire?` Assuming you have a GND pour on the other side (or one of the inner layers, if any), you can put vias on both copper pour sections (e.g. one near 1-16 text to the left and one to near 1-16 text to the top). This will make short those two copper pours through a big GND layer (as I said, I assume there's one). Or, if the chip has those pins shorted internally you can leave the layout as it is and let the connection be made through the chip. But this is not always a recommended practice.

Comment: I have GND planes on BOTH top and bottom side. PCB is 2-sided. Via-s are put to connect top and bottom GND planes. I guess I'll have to downgrade my Eagle back to version 6 when it was designed by engineers not marketing guys. -.-

Comment: @Daniel Make sure you vias are named GND (sometimes changes upon copy/paste). Also: I personally !strongly! oppose the Idea of routing a PCI-E layout on 2-layers! You are asking for trouble - serious EMI trouble. Go at-least 4-layer with two GND layers and the VCC routed on a inner layer (as tracks). 4-Layers with decent specs are as cheap as 2-layers these days.

Comment: Yeah, they are all named `GND`. Went back to 7.4 Eagle and the *same* board design doesn't have those airwires. CADSoft vs Autodesk 1:0.